# Does the Siri remote gyroscope work on tvOS simulator?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, siri-remote

If I connect my Siri remote to my MacBook via bluetooth and then run the tvOS simulator, will it detect motion events?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, motion events coming in from the Siri Remote accelerometer are usable with the simulator. **But:** You need a Mac with Bluetooth Low Energy support to be able to pair the remote. All systems labeled as Bluetooth 4 compatible work. Older systems can be upgraded to work, by purchasing a compatible bluetooth dongle, but that is probably beyond the scope of this question...